# "Rendered output", "inline", and "side-by-side" show everything as being removed then added back when it's a small edit on a long post

Tags: bug, edits, diff

I just saw [this edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/141978) to a very long post. [The markdown diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av2wv.png) of the edit looks fine, showing that six or so lines were changed, but the "rendered output" of the edit shows everything (even the image) being crossed out and then everything is highlighted as an addition. In the revision history, this is true for every revision of this post starting with [#190](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/205117/revisions?page=2) for both "inline" and "side-by-side" views.

What I think happened here is that things timed out. But I think it should be able to do better, since so much of the post was unchanged and the markdown view was able to do it right.